# Adding hint-like behavior to a spinner

Tags: android, spinner, listitem

I am trying to add a hint-like behavior to my spinner.

The needed result should work the same as EditText's hint feature - showing faded text, but the extra thing I need now here is that this text is not being added to the actual list that populates the spinner.

Here are images of what I am trying to achieve -

[image]

[image]

and here is what I have tried so far -

```
//before onCreate, on activity top variables - 
private var didChangeCountryFromDefault = false

countriesSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, pos: Int, id: Long) {
        if (!didChangeCountryFromDefault) {
            didChangeCountryFromDefault = true
            (parent.getChildAt(0) as TextView).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e4e4e4"))
            (parent.getChildAt(0) as TextView).textSize = 15f
            (parent.getChildAt(0) as TextView).text = "Select Country"
        }
    }
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
}
```

The issue I am facing is that when the activity loads up, the `onItemSelected is being called for the first time to pick the first string out of the list and I change it to "Select Country", which actually works as expected but the issue now is that I am unable to re-select the first string from the list again until I select any other string (because the first one is already selected)

How can I enable re-selection of the selected list item and not show "Select Country" again?

Comment: adding android:prompt="@string/hint_string" or spinner.setPrompt("Hint"); doesnt solve your issue?

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu no, this does abosoluty nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you want hint item not show in spinner dropdown then you can use this lbrary it will provide full customization

[Check this library](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner)

Comment: This is a good direction though using this library is quite a mess. I get the size of the spinner changed after changing from the hint to any selected item and also the arrow is being shifted up. How do I make the size the same for all texts using this library?

Comment: You can add custom layout through like this:-
app:ms_dropDownHintView="@layout/item_hint_view"
  app:ms_hintView="@layout/item_dropdown_view"

And you can define same textsize in both layout of textview

Answer (score 0):

Solved - created my own custom spinner that can listen to click of the already clicked list item and treated it as needed.